# Developing Single Page App on Force.com without using Visualforce page

Tags: angularjs, salesforce, single-page-application, force.com

Is it possible to develop Single Page Application on Force.com platform using HTML5 and AngularJS - without using Visualforce page and Salesforce's Aura framework?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use capabilities of Visualforce (Apex page controllers, visualforce tags, etc) you can develop Single Page Application with AngularJS or any other modern Javascript framework using for interaction with back-end part such ability as **Visualforce Remote Objects**. [Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects_example_simple.htm) is short example of using it. Also you can you Salesforce REST API, see [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/07/building-single-page-app-angularjs-salesforce-rest-api.html).